# Remove border/bg images on select on chrome (mac)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, macos

I'm styling a print css file to nicely print out a web page with several input elements. All looks good when printed from PC browsers but when I look at chrome on Mac a select element prints out with the rounded corners and select arrows in black (see img)

[image]
<sub>(source: [onexamination.com](http://media.onexamination.com/Images/SOE-MFD-111082612490.jpg))</sub>

css on this is

input, select {

```
border: none;
overflow: visible; 
background: none;
```

}

How do you get rid of the background things - dont even know what to call them, are they images !?

Comment: if you remove `overflow: visible;`, what does it look like? is this needed?

Comment: Could be something to do with [box shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-shadow) or [border radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius)?

Comment: Matt K  -  The overflow: visible is for an email input - just to make sure that the whole of the email address is visible when printing and not shortened by the limited width box - still looks the same with out this

Comment: Spycho - I've tried setting them both to 0 and none but  with no success

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to find a solution to this...

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

This seems to remove all rendering on the element and leave it just as the selected text when printed out.